# WPF Richtext box content

Tags: wpf, rtf

how do i get the richtext box's content with all the formatting intact.
i used a TextRange object to get the content out of the richtext box but wen i get its .text property all its formatting is gone ... how do i get the formatted content in richtext box in wpf.

Answer (score 0):

RichTextBox operates on FlowDocuments. You can get underlying FlowDocument from RichTextBox.Document property.